# How to draw curved arrows in tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am getting something like this:
[image]

This certainly doesn't look good. Curved arrows cross the blocks. Is there any better way of drawing curved arrows or any other solution?

I am putting my code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage[margin=15mm]{geometry}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,fit,calc,positioning}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[thick]
\tikzset{input/.style={}}
\tikzset{block/.style={rectangle,draw}}
\tikzstyle{pinstyle} = [pin edge={to-,thick,black}]

\node [input, name=input] {};
\node [block, right=0.5 cm of input,minimum width=1.5cm, minimum height=2.5cm] (a) {};
\node [block, right of=a,minimum width=1.5cm, minimum height=5cm,node distance=3cm] (b) {};
\node [block, right of=b, minimum width=2cm, minimum height=5cm,node distance=3cm] (c) {};
\node [block, right of=c,minimum width=1.5cm, minimum height=5cm,node distance=3cm] (d) {};
\node [block, right of=d, minimum width=2cm, minimum height=5cm,node distance=3cm] (e) {};
\node [right =0.5 cm of e] (output) {};

\begin{scope}[->,>=latex]

\draw[->] (input) -- (a);

\node at (b.center) {\footnotesize{z}};

\draw[->] ([yshift=1.5 cm]c.north west) node[left]{\footnotesize{$Ack_1$}} -| ([xshift=0.25 cm]e.north);
\draw[->] ([yshift=1.5 cm]c.north west) -| ([xshift=0.25 cm]c.north);
\draw[->] ([yshift=1 cm]c.north west) node[left]{\footnotesize{$Ack_0$}} -| ([xshift=-0.25 cm]e.north);
\draw[->] ([yshift=1 cm]c.north west) -| ([xshift=-0.25 cm]c.north);
\draw[->] (e) -- (output);

\foreach \i in {2,...,-2}{% 
\draw[->] ([yshift=\i * 0.4 cm]a.east) -- ([yshift=\i * 0.8 cm]b.west) ;}

\foreach \i in {-2,...,2}{% 
\draw[->] ([yshift=\i * 0.8 cm]b.east) -- ([yshift=\i * 0.8 cm]c.west) ;}

\foreach \i in {-2,...,2}{% 
\draw[->] ([yshift=\i * 0.4 cm]a.east) to [out=-60,in=-120] ([yshift=\i * 0.8 cm]d.west) ;}

\foreach \i in {-2,...,2}{% 
\draw[->] ([yshift=\i * 0.8 cm]d.east) -- ([yshift=\i * 0.8 cm]e.west) ;}

\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I think you know already the answer as it was given to you in your previous question [Multiple arrows between nodes](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/57285/multiple-arrows-between-nodes).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Code for Yiannis Lazarides's solution :

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[thick]
\tikzset{input/.style={}} 
\tikzset{block/.style={rectangle,draw}}
\tikzstyle{pinstyle} = [pin edge={to-,thick,black}]

\node [input, name=input] {};
\node [block, right=0.5 cm of input,minimum width=3cm, minimum height=5cm] (a) {};
\node [name = z] at ([xshift=4 cm]a.east) {};
\node [block, above=0.5 cm of z, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=5cm] (b) {};
\node [block, right=2.5 cm of b, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=5cm] (c) {};
\node [block, below=0.5 cm of z, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=5cm] (d) {};
\node [block, right=2.5 cm of d, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=5cm] (e) {};



\begin{scope}[>=latex]

\draw[->] ([yshift=1.5 cm,xshift=0.25 cm]c.north) node[right] {\footnotesize{$Ack_1$}} -- ([xshift=0.25 cm]c.north);
\draw[->] ([yshift=1.5 cm,xshift=-0.25 cm]c.north) node[left] {\footnotesize{$Ack_0$}} -- ([xshift=-0.25 cm]c.north);

\draw[->] (input) -- (a);

\draw ([yshift=1 cm,xshift=-0.25 cm]c.north)  -- ([yshift=1 cm,xshift=1 cm]c.north east);
\draw ([yshift=0.5 cm,xshift=0.25 cm]c.north)  -- ([yshift=0.5 cm,xshift=0.5 cm]c.north east);

\draw ([yshift=1 cm,xshift=1 cm]c.north east) -- ([yshift=-0.25 cm,xshift=1 cm]c.south east);
\draw ([yshift=0.5 cm,xshift=0.5 cm]c.north east) -- ([yshift=-0.75 cm,xshift=0.5 cm]c.south east);

\draw ([yshift=-0.25 cm,xshift=1 cm]c.south east) -- ([yshift=1.01 cm,xshift=-0.25 cm]e.north);
\draw ([yshift=-0.75 cm,xshift=0.5 cm]c.south east) -- ([yshift=0.51 cm,xshift=0.25 cm]e.north);

\draw[->] ([yshift=1.01 cm,xshift=-0.25 cm]e.north) -- ([xshift=-0.25 cm]e.north);
\draw[->] ([yshift=0.51 cm,xshift=0.25 cm]e.north) -- ([xshift=0.25 cm]e.north);

\foreach \i in {2,...,-2}{% 
\draw[->] ([yshift=\i * 0.8 cm]a.east) -- ([yshift=\i * 0.8 cm]b.west) ;}

\foreach \i in {2,...,-2}{% 
\draw[->] ([yshift=\i * 0.8 cm]a.east) -- ([yshift=\i * 0.8 cm]d.west) ;}

\foreach \i in {2,...,-2}{% 
\draw[->] ([yshift=\i * 0.8 cm]b.east) -- ([yshift=\i * 0.8 cm]c.west) ;}

\foreach \i in {2,...,-2}{% 
\draw[->] ([yshift=\i * 0.8 cm]d.east) -- ([yshift=\i * 0.8 cm]e.west) ;}


\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

This results into :
[image]

Answer (score 23):

you can add two points in the path of the arc

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage[margin=15mm]{geometry}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,fit,calc,positioning}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[thick]
\tikzset{input/.style={}}
\tikzset{block/.style={rectangle,draw}}
\tikzstyle{pinstyle} = [pin edge={to-,thick,black}]

\node [input, name=input] {};
\node [block, right=0.5 cm of input,minimum width=1.5cm, minimum height=2.5cm,red] (a) {};
\node [block, right of=a,minimum width=1.5cm, minimum height=5cm,node distance=3cm,blue] (b) {};
\node [block, right of=b, minimum width=2cm, minimum height=5cm,node distance=3cm,purple] (c) {};
\node [block, right of=c,minimum width=1.5cm, minimum height=5cm,node distance=3cm,green] (d) {};
\node [block, right of=d, minimum width=2cm, minimum height=5cm,node distance=3cm] (e) {};
\node [right =0.5 cm of e] (output) {};

\begin{scope}[->,>=latex]

\draw[->] (input) -- (a);

\node at (b.center) {\footnotesize{z}};

\draw[->] ([yshift=1.5 cm]c.north west) node[left]{\footnotesize{$Ack_1$}} -| ([xshift=0.25 cm]e.north);
\draw[->] ([yshift=1.5 cm]c.north west) -| ([xshift=0.25 cm]c.north);
\draw[->] ([yshift=1 cm]c.north west) node[left]{\footnotesize{$Ack_0$}} -| ([xshift=-0.25 cm]e.north);
\draw[->] ([yshift=1 cm]c.north west) -| ([xshift=-0.25 cm]c.north);
\draw[->] (e) -- (output);

\foreach \i in {2,...,-2}{% 
\draw[->] ([yshift=\i * 0.4 cm]a.east) -- ([yshift=\i * 0.8 cm]b.west) ;}

\foreach \i in {-2,...,2}{% 
\draw[->] ([yshift=\i * 0.8 cm]b.east) -- ([yshift=\i * 0.8 cm]c.west) ;}

\foreach \i in {-2,...,2}{% 
\draw[->] ([yshift=\i * 0.4 cm]a.east) to [out=-0,in=90]  ([xshift={\i * 0.15 cm-0.75cm}]b.south west) to [out=-90,in=-90]  ([xshift={-\i * 0.15 cm+0.75cm}]c.south east)  to [out=90,in=-180]  ([yshift=\i * 0.8 cm]d.west) ;}

\foreach \i in {-2,...,2}{% 
\draw[->] ([yshift=\i * 0.8 cm]d.east) -- ([yshift=\i * 0.8 cm]e.west) ;}

\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: [Cable tie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cable_tie) anyone?

Answer (score 15):

Suggestion, don't use curved arrows and simplify the diagram.

[image]

What you are conveying is that from the input block the process is split into two sub-processes. The Ack lines can be repeated at top and bottom.

I would normally sketch a diagram in a program such as OpenOffice and then draw them using TikZ for inclusion in documents. It takes me about 5 minutes with OpenOffice and anything from  three quarters of an hour (still) to an hour to get them right using TikZ, so I am not posting any code. If you adopt the approach, please post your code.

Comment: This design is also the first thing I thought of when seeing the first picture.
The first sketch can be done even more effectively and quickly with pen and paper.

Comment: @AlfredM. True, I should remind myself of Djikstra, his word processor was always hanging form a string in his office:)