# Drawing an arrow around an automata

Tags: tikz-pgf, automata

Using Tikzpicture, I have the following automata:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,arrows,automata}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth',shorten >=1pt,node distance=2cm,on grid,initial/.style={}]
\node[state,initial]  (a0)                   {};
\node[state]          (a1)  [right =of a0]   {};
\node[state]          (a2)  [right =of a1]   {};
\node[state]          (a3)  [above =of a2]   {};
\node[state]          (a4)  [below =of a0]   {};
\node[state]          (a6)  [right =of a4]   {};
\node[state]          (a7)  [right =of a2]   {};   
\node[state]          (a8)  [right =of a7]   {};
\node[state]          (a9)  [right =of a8]   {}; 
\node[state]          (a5)  [above =of a9]   {};
\node[state]          (b0)  [right =of a6]   {}; 
\node[state]          (b1)  [right =of b0]   {};
\node[state]          (b2)  [right =of b1]   {}; 
\node[state]          (b3)  [right =of b2]   {};
\node[state]          (b4)  [right =of a9]   {};                                
\tikzset{every node/.style={fill=white}}
\tikzset{mystyle/.style={->,double=red}}  
\path (a4)     edge [mystyle]       node   {$0$} (a6)
      (a2)     edge [mystyle]       node   {$0$} (a7)
      (b0)     edge [mystyle]       node   {$0$} (b1);
\tikzset{mystyle/.style={->,double=blue}}  
\path (a3)     edge [mystyle]       node   {$1$} (a5)
      (a8)     edge [mystyle]       node   {$1$} (a9)
      (b2)     edge [mystyle]       node   {$1$} (b3);              
\tikzset{mystyle/.style={->,double=yellow}}  
\path (a0)     edge [mystyle]       node   {$\varepsilon$} (a1)
      (a1)     edge [mystyle]       node   {$\varepsilon$} (a2)
      (a1)     edge [mystyle]       node   {$\varepsilon$} (a3)
      (a1)     edge [mystyle]       node   {$\varepsilon$} (a4)
      (a6)     edge [mystyle]       node   {$\varepsilon$} (b0)
      (a7)     edge [mystyle]       node   {$\varepsilon$} (a8)
      (b1)     edge [mystyle]       node   {$\varepsilon$} (b2)
      (a9)     edge [mystyle]       node   {$\varepsilon$} (b4)
      (a5)     edge [mystyle]       node   {$\varepsilon$} (b4)
      (b3)     edge [mystyle]       node   {$\varepsilon$} (b4);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image: Result]

Now, I want to add a yellow epsilon arrow from the node on the far left (a0) to the node on the far right (b4).  However, I have absolutely no idea how to do this without the arrow cutting through the rest of the automata.   Can I get some help here?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436). While code snippets are useful in explanations, it is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.

This is especially important for `tikz` as there are numerous libraries.

Comment: @Minhtam: Add `\draw [mystyle] (a0) to [bend left=90] (b4);` to draw a curved arrow. You can specify the curvature using the parameter to `bend left`.

Comment: look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/94663/automaton-backedge-arrows-running-into-other-states and http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/57571/how-to-draw-curved-arrows-in-tikz/57576#57576

Answer (score 10):

You can use `[bend left]` option as suggested in a comment, and give it an angle, such as `[bend left=70]`, then the curve will leave then start and ending nodes at that angle, and thus the resulting path is symmetric.

```
(a0)   edge[mystyle, bend left=70] node {$\varepsilon$} (b4);
```

However, in this particular case, since the figure is assymetric, this way of producing the path looks a bit ugly (imho):

[image: A bit ugly]

Through options `in` and `out` you can specify different angles for the endings of the path, and thus create an assymetric arc which fits better with the rest of the figure:

```
 (a0)   edge[mystyle, out=50,in=90] node {$\varepsilon$} (b4);
```

[image: Better]