# Make a TikZ automata edge pass "outside " the automata

Tags: tikz-pgf, automata

I am trying to draw a Moore machine with TikZ. This is what I have so far:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,automata,positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex',shorten >=1pt,node distance=3cm,on grid,auto]
  \node[state,initial] (q0-e) {$q_0/\epsilon$};
  \node[state] (q0-1) [below right=of q0-e] {$q_0'/1$};
  \node[state] (q1-0) [above right=of q0-1] {$q_1/0$};
  \node[state] (q2-1) [below right=of q1-0] {$q_2/1$};
  \node[state,accepting] (q3-0) [below left=of q0-1] {$q_3/0$};
  \node[state,accepting] (q3-1) [below right=of q0-1] {$q_3'/1$};
  \path[->] (q0-e) edge node {a} (q1-0);
  \path[->] (q0-e) edge node {b} (q3-0);
  \path[->] (q0-1) edge node {a} (q1-0);
  \path[->] (q0-1) edge [bend right] node {b} (q3-0);
  \path[->] (q1-0) edge [bend left=90,looseness=2.5] node {a} (q3-1);
  \path[->] (q1-0) edge node {b} (q2-1);
  \path[->] (q2-1) edge node {a} (q0-1);
  \path[->] (q2-1) edge node {b} (q3-1);
  \path[->] (q3-0) edge node {a} (q3-1);
  \path[->] (q3-0) edge [bend right] node {b} (q0-1);
  \path[->] (q3-1) edge [loop below] node {a} (q3-1);
  \path[->] (q3-1) edge node {b} (q0-1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

And it produces the automaton below:

[image: Moore machine]

But I would like to have the edge from $q_1/0$ to $q_3'/1$ to pass "outside" the automaton, like shown by the red line of the following picture:

[image: Moore machine with line indicating the desired drawing]

Can anyone show how to achieve that? Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. Does the answer to this question help? http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/103728/drawing-an-arrow-around-an-automata

Comment: You can achieve that either with the `.. controls` path operator or with for example the `bend left` to path or `out` and `in`. You already used something similar in the diagram.

Comment: Your example isn't good. See this: [I've just been asked to write a minimal example, what is that?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that), to learn about a good minimal working example.

Answer (score 7):

For that effect, extra points are needed. Here Bezier curve is used where two extra points are located 4cm to right of points (q1-0) and (q3-1) and then command `(p1) .. controls (p2) and (p3) .. (p4);` is applied. Also `calc` from tikzlibrary is used to compute the coordinates.

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{automata,arrows,trees,positioning,shapes,calc}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex',shorten >=1pt,node distance=3cm,on grid,auto]
  \node[state,initial] (q0-e) {$q_0/\epsilon$};
  \node[state] (q0-1) [below right=of q0-e] {$q_0'/1$};
  \node[state] (q1-0) [above right=of q0-1] {$q_1/0$};
  \node[state] (q2-1) [below right=of q1-0] {$q_2/1$};
  \node[state,accepting] (q3-0) [below left=of q0-1] {$q_3/0$};
  \node[state,accepting] (q3-1) [below right=of q0-1] {$q_3'/1$};
  \path[->] (q0-e) edge node {a} (q1-0);
  \path[->] (q0-e) edge node {b} (q3-0);
  \path[->] (q0-1) edge node {a} (q1-0);
  \path[->] (q0-1) edge [bend right] node {b} (q3-0);
  \path[->] (q1-0) edge node {a} (q3-1);
  \path[->] (q1-0) edge node {b} (q2-1);
  \path[->] (q2-1) edge node {a} (q0-1);
  \path[->] (q2-1) edge node {b} (q3-1);
  \path[->] (q3-0) edge node {a} (q3-1);
  \path[->] (q3-0) edge [bend right] node {b} (q0-1);
  \path[->] (q3-1) edge [loop below] node {a} (q3-1);
  \path[->] (q3-1) edge node {b} (q0-1);
  \draw [->,thick,red] (q1-0) ..  controls  ($(q1-0)+(4cm,0)$) and
  ($(q3-1)+(4cm,0)$) ..  (q3-1);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```