# How do I pass a curved line through a relative coordinate in a polygon using Tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf, coordinates, polygon, arrow-curve

I haven't found an answer that quite fits my situation. I need to link two rectangles, with a curved arrow, passing through the bottom right of a third rectangle, avoiding the text.

I'm using a university-specific document type, so hopefully the below MWE is okay using a normal document style.

```
 \documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
 \usepackage[english]{babel}
 \usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}
 \usepackage{amsfonts}
 \usepackage[a4paper,layout=a4paper,
        bindingoffset=4cm,left=0cm,right=2cm,
        head=2.5cm, bmargin=2cm]{geometry}
 \usepackage{microtype} 
 \usepackage{verbatim}
 \usepackage{graphicx}
 \usepackage{url}  
 \usepackage[round]{natbib} 
 \usepackage{listings}
 \usepackage{booktabs}
 \usepackage{multirow} 
 \RequirePackage[l2tabu, orthodox]{nag}
 \usepackage{tikz} 
 \usetikzlibrary{arrows, shapes, chains, fit, backgrounds, calc, decorations.pathreplacing, matrix}
 \usepackage{hyperref}
 \usepackage{cleveref} 
 \usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
 \usepackage[inline, shortlabels]{enumitem} 
 \usepackage{tikzlings}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htbp]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style=draw, align=center, arrow/.style={thick, -stealth}]
\node[rectangle, fill=white] (PSRW) {One \\ two three \\ four five \\ six};
\node [right, single arrow, inner sep = 10pt, minimum height=1cm, rotate=-45, above left = of PSRW, xshift=1cm, yshift=-.3cm] (NW) {};
\cat[scale=0.6, above right = of PSRW, xshift=10cm, yshift=0cm] (ACat) {};
\mouse[scale=0.5, above right = of PSRW, xshift=13.5cm, yshift=0cm] (AMouse) {};

\node[draw=none, text width=2cm, above right = of PSRW, xshift = 6cm, yshift=-2.5cm] (Imp) {Seven \\ Eight \\ Nine \\ Ten \\ Eleven};

\node[draw=none, text width=2.5cm, below = 3cm of PSRW] (SC) {Twelve \\ Thirteen};
% lines here omitted for brevity
 \node[draw=none, text width=1cm, above right = of SC, xshift=1cm, yshift=-.8cm] (TI) {Twelve, \\ thirteen};
   \end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Horrible part diagram of hand drawn one}
\label{fig:ThisDiagramIsDrivingMeToDrink}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

The problem is that I need to draw an **arrow** that goes from the left of the mice, through the bottom right of the PSRW rectangle, and attaches to the north west of the TI box. I would like to use a coordinate system relative to the internal bottom right of the PRSW box. I think that perhaps my supervisors won't like my little images, so that detail there may shift and I don't want to rewrite a bunch of coordinates to deal with any shifting.

I tried:

```
   \draw[arrow] ([xshift=-3cm]Imp.west) to [bend right, looseness=2] (TI.west);
```

but it doesn't pass through the PSRW box:
[image: My unsuccessful attempt to draw the curved arrow]

I've seen answers based on relative coordinates to the underlying geometry, but none based on relative coordinates to polygons that may shift position.

Perhaps the closest answer I have seen is for the opposite problem [so that the curved lines are outside the polygons](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/57571/how-to-draw-curved-arrows-in-tikz). The other answers tend to be like this one, which [are linking two points directly with a curve](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228724/how-do-i-make-tikz-make-a-curved-arrow-from-one-node-to-another-when-my-nodes-ar).

I can't show the actual (handwritten) diagram that I am trying to replicate due to academic paywall. But if any of you have access to Peter Checkland's work on soft systems methodology, I'm trying to replicate his two-stream diagram using Tikz.

Because of the complexity of the diagram, and my ongoing need to adjust parts of it to fit on the page, I have to place the polygons before I place the arrows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Meow. You can draw a smooth plot through these coordinates.

```
\draw[thick,-stealth] plot[smooth] coordinates 
    {([yshift=3mm,xshift=-1mm]tikzlings.south west) ([xshift=-1mm,yshift=1mm]PSRW.south east) (TI.north west)};
```

Full code:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.arrows,positioning}

\usepackage{tikzlings}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style=draw, align=center, arrow/.style={thick, -stealth}]
 \node[rectangle, fill=white] (PSRW) {One \\ two three \\ four five \\ six};
 \node[single arrow, inner sep = 10pt, minimum height=1cm, rotate=-45, above
    left =9mm and 4mm of PSRW.north west,anchor=north] (NW) {};
 \begin{scope}[local bounding box=tikzlings]
  \cat[scale=0.6, above right = of PSRW, xshift=10cm, yshift=0cm] (ACat) {};
  \mouse[scale=0.5, above right = of PSRW, xshift=13.5cm, yshift=0cm] (AMouse) {};
 \end{scope} 
 \node[draw=none, text width=2cm, above right = of PSRW, xshift = 6cm, yshift=-2.5cm] (Imp) {Seven \\ Eight \\ Nine \\ Ten \\ Eleven};
 \node[draw=none, text width=2.5cm, below = 3cm of PSRW] (SC) {Twelve \\ Thirteen};
 \node[draw=none, text width=1cm, above right = of SC, xshift=1cm, yshift=-.8cm] (TI) {Twelve, \\ thirteen};
 \draw[thick,-stealth] plot[smooth] coordinates 
    {([yshift=3mm,xshift=-1mm]tikzlings.south west) ([xshift=-1mm,yshift=1mm]PSRW.south east) (TI.north west)};
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: LOL, apt username. How do I make that curve pass slightly inside the PSRW box, so xshift and yshift relate to PSRW.south east? Do I use the same shift logic as for the tikzlings?

Comment: @Michelle E.g. `\draw[thick,-stealth] plot[smooth] coordinates 
  {([yshift=3mm,xshift=-1mm]tikzlings.south west) ([xshift=-1mm,yshift=1mm]PSRW.south east) (TI.north west)};` (but now this makes the impression that we cats cut the corners. ;-)

Comment: haha good one meow